# Loop incomplete

Tags: c, loops

I just started learning coding for about 2 months because of the course im taking. 
My code works (kinda) but after the 1st loop it wont show the 1st line of the main function("You have been given 20 pokeballs, embrak on you quest on becoming a Pokeman Master!!!:), and i dont know why!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int pokeball = 20;
int rand_num;
int PokemonCaught[5] = { 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0 };
int poke_captured = 0;
int rungame = 1;
int stopgame = 1;
int total;

int randomnum();
int encounter_rate();
int pokemon_met();
void BallThrow();
void CaughtPokemon();
void checkball();
void PokeSummary();
char exitno();
int clear();

int main()
{
    printf("You have been given 20 pokeballs, embrak on you quest on becoming a Pokeman Master!!!\n");
    getchar();

    do
    {
        checkball();
        encounter_rate();
        pokemon_met();
    } while (stopgame == 0);

    PokeSummary();

    return 0;
}

int randomnum()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
}

int encounter_rate()
{
    randomnum();
    rand_num = rand() % 100;
}

int pokemon_met()
{
    if (rand_num <= 30)
    {
        printf("A wild Margikarp appeared!.\n");
        printf("Press ENTER to throw a pokeball!. \n");
        getchar();

        rungame = 1;
        BallThrow();
    }

    else if (rand_num <= 50)
    {
        printf("A wild Charmander appeared!.\n");
        printf("Press ENTER to throw a pokeball!. \n");
        getchar();

        rungame = 1;
        BallThrow();
    }

    else if (rand_num <= 70)
    {
        printf("A wild Jigglypuff appeared!.\n");
        printf("Press ENTER to throw a pokeball!. \n");
        getchar();

        rungame = 1;
        BallThrow();
    }

    else if (rand_num <= 85)
    {
        printf("A wild Pikachu appeared!.\n");
        printf("Press ENTER to throw a pokeball!. \n");
        getchar();

        rungame = 1;
        BallThrow();
    }

    else 
    {
        printf("A wild Dragonite appeared!.\n");
        printf("Press ENTER to throw a pokeball!. \n");
        getchar();

        rungame = 1;
        BallThrow();
    }
}

void checkball()
{
    if (pokeball > 0)
    {
        stopgame = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        stopgame = 1;
    }
}

void BallThrow()
{
        randomnum();
        int BallChance;
        int PokeRun;
        BallChance = rand() % 2;
        pokeball = pokeball - 1;
        if (BallChance == 1)
        {
            printf("Gotcha!\n");
            printf("Number of Pokeball left: %d\n", pokeball);
            printf("Press ENTER to continue your journey!\n\n");
            poke_captured = poke_captured + 1;
            CaughtPokemon();
            getchar();

            if (pokeball == 0)
            {
                printf("Your pokeball has used up!\n");
                printf("Press ENTER to check the summary of your journey\n");

                getchar();

                PokeSummary();
            }
        }
        else if (BallChance == 0)
        {
            PokeRun = rand() % 2;
            printf("The pokemon broke free!!!\n");
            if (PokeRun == 0)
            {
                if (pokeball == 0)
                {
                    printf("Your pokeball has used up!\n");
                    printf("Press ENTER to check the summary of your journey\n");

                    getchar();

                    PokeSummary();
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Number of Pokeball left: %d\n", pokeball);
                    printf("Press ENTER to throw pokeball!\n\n");
                    getchar();

                    BallThrow();
                }
            }
            else if (PokeRun == 1)
            {
                printf("Oh no! The pokemon ran away!\n");
                printf("Number of Pokeball left: %d\n", pokeball);
                printf("Press ENTER to continue your journey!\n\n");
                getchar();
                if (pokeball == 0)
                {
                    printf("Your pokeball has used up!\n");
                    printf("Press ENTER to check the summary of your journey\n");

                    getchar();

                    PokeSummary();

                }
            }
        }
}

void CaughtPokemon()
{

    if (rand_num <= 30)
    {
        PokemonCaught[0] = PokemonCaught[0] + 1;
    }
    else if (rand_num <= 50)
    {
        PokemonCaught[1] = PokemonCaught[1] + 1;
    }
    else if (rand_num <= 70)
    {
        PokemonCaught[2] = PokemonCaught[2] + 1;
    }
    else if (rand_num <= 85)
    {
        PokemonCaught[3] = PokemonCaught[3] + 1;
    }
    else if (rand_num <= 95)
    {
        PokemonCaught[4] = PokemonCaught[4] + 1;
    }
}

void PokeSummary()
{
    int point0, point1, point2, point3, point4, total;

    point0 = (PokemonCaught[0]) * 10;
    point1 = (PokemonCaught[1]) * 30;
    point2 = (PokemonCaught[2]) * 30;
    point3 = (PokemonCaught[3]) * 50;
    point4 = (PokemonCaught[4]) * 70;
    total = point0 + point1 + point2 + point3 + point4;

    printf("You have successfully caught %d Pokemon!\n\n", poke_captured);
    printf("You have caught:\n");
    printf("Margikarp = %d  (%dpoints)\n", PokemonCaught[0], point0);
    printf("Charmander = %d (%dpoints)\n", PokemonCaught[1], point1);
    printf("Jigglypuff = %d (%dpoints)\n", PokemonCaught[2], point2);
    printf("Pikachu = %d    (%dpoints)\n", PokemonCaught[3], point3);
    printf("Dragonite = %d  (%dpoints)\n", PokemonCaught[4], point4);
    printf("\nTotal points = %d\n", total);

    exitno();
}

char exitno()
{

    char stay;

    printf("Press 'y' to continue, press any other key to quit.");
    scanf(" %c", &stay);

    if (stay == 'y' || stay == 'Y')
    {
        clear();
        return (main);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Thank you for playing!!");
        exit(0);
    }
}

int clear()
{
    total = total * 0;
    poke_captured = poke_captured * 0;
    PokemonCaught[0] = PokemonCaught[0] * 0;
    PokemonCaught[1] = PokemonCaught[1] * 0;
    PokemonCaught[2] = PokemonCaught[2] * 0;
    PokemonCaught[3] = PokemonCaught[3] * 0;
    PokemonCaught[4] = PokemonCaught[4] * 0;
    pokeball = pokeball + 20;
}
```

I appreciate any help and i know my codes are far from being decent (sigh)
. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please compile your program with all warnings enabled. What is `return (main);`in the `exitno` function?

Comment: ... and google "c abuse global variable".

Comment: i placed it there having the thought that it returns to the main function from the exitno function. i dont have much ideas on how to return it....

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an error when calling main in `char exitno()` function:

char exitno()
{

```
char stay;

printf("Press 'y' to continue, press any other key to quit.");
scanf(" %c", &stay);

if (stay == 'y' || stay == 'Y')
{
    clear();
    return ((char)main()); // main it should be called using parenthesis
}
else
{
    printf("Thank you for playing!!");
    exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: ((char)main()) means the character is returned to the main function?

Answer (score 0):

That is not inside of your do-while loop.
If you want it to execute every time, then just move it down into the the loop.  Otherwise, your program will move past in the first few milliseconds of operation.  Alternatively, modify it (likely, put it within a new function) to print out some information that might change during execution of your program--say, the current number of pokeballs remaining.

Comment: wait i included the line in the loop but then it appears everytime not after i rerun my program....